# Display offset. See image

Tags: lubuntu, display

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, but I have installed the package `lubuntu-desktop`. Everything was fine till one day, the screen went offset. You can see the grey background at the sides [image: Grey background is the screen offset]. Windows can only be maximized as much as the desktop background. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Had you installed just before something?

Comment: I might have installed something, or it might have been the upgrades. I don't remember. But I certainly did not manually change any settings.

Comment: Okay. Nice question by the way :) Does the mouse go into there?

Comment: Yes. It does goes there. Also when I tried to right click there on the grey background, the background came over the start button at the lower left corner.  And now I cannot see the button, nor click it.

Comment: You can't click the start button? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2212840 has the same issue, but no real solution - try it if you can.

Comment: Even my margins are already 0. But I guess mine will be lubuntu 14.04 and not 12.04 right? My packages are also up to date.

Comment: And a restart didn't solve it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24474/discussion-between-miheer-and-tim).

Comment: You could try re-installing the `lubuntu-desktop` package and maybe fixing any missing dependency problems? 
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop && sudo apt-get install -f`

Just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here, just solved. It's actually quite simple, just didn't think about it.

Just right click over the grey area, you should read something like "close this panel" (translation might not be accurate because I use the italian version of this distro), click on that and the screen automatically 
resizes. 
I don't know how I managed to create the problem first though.

Comment: I didn't realize those were panels.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed openbox as your window-manager? If you haven't install it, as well as obconf, obmenu, and possibly lxsession-edit. The configuration files are in /etc/xdg/openbox dir.

Check and see if you have a $HOME/.config/openbox directory, and whats in that directory, by running the following commands:

```
:~$ stat $HOME/.config/openbox

:~$ ls $HOME/.config/openbox
```

If you don't have have the directory, create it, and copy everything from /etc/xdg/openbox to that directory.

In the case that the directory ($HOME/.config/openbox) doesn't exist, yet you have openbox installed run these commands:

```
:~$ mkdir -p -m0755 $HOME/.config/openbox

:~$ sudo bash

:~# cp -rf /etc/xdg/openbox/* $HOME/.config/openbox/

:~# chown -R yourusername:yourusername $HOME/.config/openbox

:~# exit
```

NOTE: you should have that directory, and there should be a file titled
lubuntu-rc.xml in that directory.

Now you can edit your moving and resizing options, as well as your margins options via the $HOME/.config/lubuntu-rc.xml, or the openbox configuration manager. You might also be able to do this with lxsession-edit.

But as you can tell, the DE is not finding (or setting) the dimensions of your screen properly at startup, therefore is not centering itself.
Basically how it works, the code uses some simple math, subtraction of coordinates off the x and y axis, using a few built in functions and the total x,y pixel length of your screen's size; to get centered. So yours has gonna screwy because your configuration got mangled somehow.

This could also be because you made changes to the SystemSettings>Display, most notably it has occurred while connecting a machine to another Monitor with different dimensional specs (e.g. laptop to Flatscreen TV with a hdmi cable).

As a possible debugging test:
When you boot, on the top panel of the lubuntu login manager, on the right side there is icon that will allow to select openbox, as well as lubuntu-netbook. Play with these options (login into each one) to see if the issue is occurring across the board on all of the openbox derivatives (the DE's that use openbox as the window manager).

Comment: I tried to login using openbox. There I do not face this issue. It is only there in lubuntu. In the lubuntu-rc.xml file the margins are already 0.  What field should I change there?